# Mule Munit test with maven : mule-domain-config.xml file not found?

Tags: maven, testing, mule, pom.xml, munit

Mule Munit test with maven : mule-domain-config.xml file not found

I am getting an error while trying to run Munit using Maven. It's a domain project and my Munit test cases are available in mule projects. when I ran maven, it is giving me file not found exception (mule-domain-config.xml). I tried all possible ways by checking in this site but of no luck. Below is the stack trace.

`INFO 2017-01-06 01:15:01,226 [main] org.mule.munit.runner.MuleContextManager: Loading mule-app.properties ... INFO 2017-01-06 01:15:01,319 [main] org.mule.munit.runner.domain.MunitDomainContextBuilder: Loading mule-deploy.properties ... java.lang.RuntimeException: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: mule-domain-config.xml (java.io.FileNotFoundException)`

i already checked my pom configuration and i used an AnypointStudio.exe clean also.

Answer (score 0):

Please add domain project dependency with test scope to your pom file like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>domain project group id</groupId>
    <artifactId>domain project name</artifactId>
    <version>domain version</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are loading your mule domain config xml in your munit settings.

For instance...

```
<munit:config name="munit" doc:name="MUnit configuration"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:import resource="classpath:my-munit-test.xml"/>
    <spring:import resource="mule-domain-config.xml"/>
</spring:beans>
<munit:test name="tesad-test-suite-FlowTest"...
```

Check the `spring:import` lines

Also, as @anupambhusari said , please check that you are importing your domain config properly

Comment: Hi there, just FYI adding the domain dependency should be enough. No need to import the file in the MUnit test suite

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you found a solution of this problem, but I got this working by adding Mule domain project in build path, from Configure Build Path option.